# Missing 'rect' attribute in RenderLayer

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

According to this simple external renderer, result can be generated in the memory instead of loading from an external file.

```
    # In this example, we fill the full renders with a flat blue color.
    def render_scene(self, scene):
    pixel_count = self.size_x * self.size_y

    # The framebuffer is defined as a list of pixels, each pixel
    # itself being a list of R,G,B,A values
    blue_rect = [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]] * pixel_count

    # Here we write the pixel values to the RenderResult
    result = self.begin_result(0, 0, self.size_x, self.size_y)
    layer = result.layers[0]
    layer.rect = blue_rect
    self.end_result(result)
```

I got an missing 'rect' attribute error from Blender 2.75.

Here is the error

```
layer.rect = blue_rect
AttributeError: 'RenderLayer' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

The 'rect' attribute was still there in 2.67.1 version blender, is it deprecated in the latest version?

How should I update partial intermediate result in Blender? The only solution that I can find is to update the full image with "load_from_file" function which takes a filename parameter and loads the data from file system.

Answer (score 1):

Use `layer.passes[0].rect = blue_rect` instead of `layer.rect` in your code.